# OR Condition in JSON filter Wave analytics Dashboard

Tags: lightning, einstein-analytics, saql

I have a json filter in lightning record page for a Analytics dashboard. There are conditions where Code1__c will be NULL or Code2__c will be NULL . Is there any mechanism in JSON filter where we can put OR condition to use Code__1 if Code2__c is NULL and viceversa. Currently dashboard is taking both the fields which is failing the dashboard to display data.
Any ideas....

```
{ 
   'datasets':{ 
      'OpportunityProducts':[ 
         { 
            'fields':[ 
               'Opportunity.Account.Code1__c'
            ],
            'selection':[ 
               '$Code1__c'

            ],
            'filter':{ 
               'operator':'matches',
               'values':[ 
                  '$Code1__c'  
               ]
            }
         },
         { 
            'fields':[ 
            'Opportunity.Account.Code2__c'
            ],
            'selection':[ 
               '$Code2__c'
            ],
            'filter':{ 
               'operator':'matches',
               'values':[ 
                  '$Code2__c'
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula editor in the compare table, or write the SAQL itself.

Both ways, you are going to use the coalesce function:
coalesce(Code1__c, Code2__c)

However there are still certain situations to consider:
Can only one of the values be filled? If so, the above code would be sufficient.
If not, you have to decide if Code1__c or Code2__c should be displayed (That field has to be the first argument of the coalesce funtion).

Can both values be null? Should there be something in that field like a message "both values null" or an empty string? That has to be added as a third argument.